# Export data to excel and pdf ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, pdf, pdf-generation

I want to save my view result in web to excel and or PDF. I must show dialog save to make path and choose the file's extension to make file. I use asp.net, Could you help me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

for pdf use this library wkhtmltopdf
for excel use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
if you problem with this library ask me.